# Why do some webpack / Babel ES6 imports that don't specify an extension resolve as "undefined?"

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Some ES6 files (`.js`, .`jsx`, `.ts`, `.tsx`) that I attempt to import with the syntax `import ComponentName from './folder/ComponentName';` (no extension) resolve as `undefined`, despite triggering no Webpack nor Typescript errors and resolving correctly when I add the file extension. Other files resolve fine, with or without extension. Why is this?

While it usually happens with React components, it can happen no matter the contents of the imported file, and whether or not it has a default export.

Comment: Are you using Webpack 1.x or Webpack 2.x?

Comment: @AluanHaddad Webpack 1.x

Answer (score 1):

It's because those files had neighbor of the same name but different extension (e.g. '.less') in the same directory. For example, I would have both `ComponentName.tsx` and `ComponentName.less` in the same folder.

Two possible fixes:

1. In the Webpack config `resolves` section, move the JS/ES6/TypeScript extensions in front of the `.less` / `.css` extensions, e.g. from `['.less', '.tsx', ...]` to `['.tsx', '.less', ...]`. This way, the JavaScript files resolve first.
2. Even better, don't keep files of the same name in the same directory.